# Find points within polygon with multiple self intersections with Matlab

Tags: matlab, polygon, mask

I have a polygon which intersects itself multiple times. I try to create a mask from this polygon, i.e., to find all points/pixels location within the polygon. I use the Matlab function poly2mask for this. However, due to the multiple self-intersections this is the results I obtain:

[Resulting mask from poly2mask for multi-self-intersecting polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQuNt.png)

So, some areas remain unmasked, because of the intersections. I think Matlab sees this as some sort of inclusions. The Matlab help for poly2mask doesn't mention anything about this. Does anyone have an idea how to also include these regions in the mask?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I'm thinking about using [`boundary`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html), but I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtain good results combining a small erosion/dilation step and `imfill` as follows:

```
data = load('polygon_edge.mat');
x = data.polygon_edge(:, 1);
y = data.polygon_edge(:, 2);

bw1 = poly2mask(x,y,ceil(max(y)),ceil(max(x)));
se = strel('sphere',1);
bw2 = imerode(imdilate(bw1,se), se);
bw3 = imfill(bw2, 'holes');
figure
imshow(bw3)
hold on
plot(x(:, 1),y(:, 1),'g','LineWidth',2)
```

The small erosion and dilation step is needed to be sure that all the regions are connected even at places where the polygon is only connected through a single point, otherwise `imfill` may see some non-existing holes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first calculate the boundary of your polygon and use this to create your mask.

```
k = boundary(x, y, 0.99); % 1 == tightest single-region boundary
BW = poly2mask(x(k), y(k), m, n)
```

Using a shrink factor of 0.99 instead of 1 avoids undercutting, but sharp non-convex corners are still not fitted correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, for my data set even the most stringent 'Shrink Factor' does not give the correct outer boundary. Otherwise this would have been a great solution.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample polygon, so I can test it?

Comment: Here's a link to a zip-file containing a mat-file with the polygon: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cpu8u18ke4j9gf/polygon_edge.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

you can use `inpolygon`:

```
bw1 = poly2mask(x,y,1000,1000);
subplot(131)
imshow(bw1)
hold on
plot(x([1:end 1]),y([1:end 1]),'g','LineWidth',2)
title('using poly2mask')

[xq,yq] = meshgrid(1:1000);
[IN,ON] = inpolygon(xq,yq,x,y);
bw2 = IN | ON;
subplot(132)
imshow(bw2)
hold on
plot(x([1:end 1]),y([1:end 1]),'g','LineWidth',2)
title('using inpolygon')

% boundary - seggested by another answer
k = boundary(x, y, 1); % 1 == tightest single-region boundary
bw3 = poly2mask(x(k), y(k), 1000, 1000);
subplot(133)
imshow(bw3)
hold on
plot(x([1:end 1]),y([1:end 1]),'g','LineWidth',2)
title('using boundary')
```

**Update** - I updated my answer to include `boundary` - it not seems to work well in my case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me 'inpolygon' gives the same result as 'poly2mask', unfortunately. Also, I'd rather like to avoid inpolygon, since it is taking much more time than poly2mask, because of the large amount of pixels I have (1024x768). Poly2mask takes advantage of the fact that they are on a regular grid. With the 'boundary' functions I have the same issue as you, even if I set the 'Shrink Factor' very strict.